# JavascriptMVC: CanJS loading without jQuery

Tags: jquery, javascriptmvc, canjs, stealjs

I cannot find in the documentation any "official" way to steal (stealjs) **canJS** without loading jquery.
The problem is that I'm working with **Yii Framework** (PHP) and some components need jquery before even i include **myapp.js** modules, that is i must include jquery before everything.
Now when i include **myapp.js** it also steals canJS that in turn will load jquery again breaking my application (2 instance of jquery running).
How can i steal **canJS** without jquery?

Comment: http://canjs.us/release/1.1.5/can.yui.js

Comment: I dont want to load yui, i want to loading canJS without the "library" because it shoudl be already loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This probably isn't an ideal solution, but you can create an empty dummy.js file and map jquery's path to that in stealconfig.js:

```
steal.config({
  ...
  paths: {
    "jquery": "dummy.js"
  }
  ...
})
```

Comment: mhm....honestly I thought about it too, but yes isn't an ideal solution, but it works like a charm XD.