# How do you use a page's existing jQuery + Twitter Bootstrap/plugins with StealJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, stealjs

I have a project that uses Twitter Bootstrap 3, however, I am supplementing the existing javascript situation with a CanJS app.  For CanJS dependency management I chose their package StealJS.  However, it appears that no matter what I do, StealJS insists on loading jQuery again, overwriting $.fn, of course.

[In this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16296539/javascriptmvc-canjs-loading-without-jquery) a core contributor answers that the solution is to "steal" a blank.js file.  However, this breaks steal/build for production as can/util/jquery/jquery.js is passed 'jquery' as undefined (the results of blank.js).

I have tried variations on StealJS's stealconfig.js settings including map, paths, and completed but nothing seems to work.

Here is an example of [doing this in RequireJS](http://www.manuel-strehl.de/dev/load_jquery_before_requirejs.en.html).  Is the solution simply not to use StealJS and to use RequireJS instead?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try a solution that is similar to the RequieJS solution you linked to. That is, create a dummy file that looks like this:

```
steal(function(){
    return window.jQuery;
});
```

And in stealconfig.js map `jquery` to wherever you put this file.

Comment: Though this still prohibits building production files I guess.

Comment: I will post a new question.  Something tells me these will be helpful to people in the future.